# Complex Localization with MVC ASP.NET

Tags: model-view-controller, localization, translation

We currently have a Web Forms set up for our website and are looking to slowly convert this to MVC. Currently we store translations in a database. our  translation table contains columns for each language and a sort of title. which we can identify the translation with(The primary key)

But it gets more complex when we actually may have different clients wanting different words for the same bit of text.

E.g. one will want it to read - Delivery Costs
And the next may want it as - Delivery Prices

So we then have a second CustomTranslation datatable which will be the same as the translation but also have a client ID number in it. If the user logged in and it looking for the Identify of the translation as "DeliveryCost" it will check to see if there is a  record in the CustomTranslation table it will use that OVER the standard Translation table.

After which it will then pick the appropriate language the users wants.

Basically I need to be able to have our website translate depending on the users settings. And as well as the company they work for (our client)

The general method of localization uses resource files but we need to really keep them in the database. This produces a second problem which is when you try to declare Propertry Display Names and Validation Messages these also need to ability to have different text and/or translations but generally it expects a Static field which we would not have.

Whats the best way to go about solving this complex localization issue?

Thanks in advance. Steve

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1 - Having the resources in the database**
Use the approach used in [this article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/01/Updated-WestwindGlobalization-Data-Driven-Resource-Provider-for-ASPNET) for extending the standard resources into the database.

**Problem 2 - Having custom localization per customer**
No problem, the standard .net approach supports localization including a region or customer, just use i.e. en-US, en-US-Customer1, en-US-Customer2, etc.

Comment: interesting by having en-US-Customer1 and en-US. If a translation was missing for eu-US-Customer1 it would fall back to en-US?